# Using ntlm authentication in Nativescript ios platform

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, ntlm, des

I am building an app with authenticates the user against a sharepoint site which uses NTLM authentication. I found the ntlm.js which has been patched for nativescript here https://github.com/hdeshev/nativescript-ntlm-demo.

I have managed to get it working for android platform, but it fails on ios showing an 401 error. As far as I can tell, the difference happens in this segment:

```
Ntlm.setCredentials = function(domain, username, password) {
    var magic = 'KGS!@#$%'; // Create LM password hash.
    var lmPassword = password.toUpperCase().substr(0, 14);
    while (lmPassword.length < 14) lmPassword += '\0';
    var key1 = Ntlm.createKey(lmPassword);
    var key2 = Ntlm.createKey(lmPassword.substr(7));
    var lmHashedPassword = des(key1, magic, 1, 0) + des(key2, magic, 1, 0);
    var ntPassword = ''; // Create NT password hash.
    for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++)
        ntPassword += password.charAt(i) + '\0';
    var ntHashedPassword = str_md4(ntPassword);
    Ntlm.domain = domain;
    Ntlm.username = username;
    Ntlm.lmHashedPassword = lmHashedPassword;
    Ntlm.ntHashedPassword = ntHashedPassword;
};
```

When I log the result of 'lmhashedPassword' after going through the `des()` function, it simply returns 'A'. Whereas on android, it returns a longer string. Something in the `des` function must be cutting it off, but I cannot see what.

Here is the `des` function:

```
function des (key, message, encrypt, mode, iv, padding) {
    //declaring this locally speeds things up a bit
    var spfunction1 = new Array (0x1010400,0,0x10000,0x1010404,0x1010004,0x10404,0x4,0x10000,0x400,0x1010400,0x1010404,0x400,0x1000404,0x1010004,0x1000000,0x4,0x404,0x1000400,0x1000400,0x10400,0x10400,0x1010000,0x1010000,0x1000404,0x10004,0x1000004,0x1000004,0x10004,0,0x404,0x10404,0x1000000,0x10000,0x1010404,0x4,0x1010000,0x1010400,0x1000000,0x1000000,0x400,0x1010004,0x10000,0x10400,0x1000004,0x400,0x4,0x1000404,0x10404,0x1010404,0x10004,0x1010000,0x1000404,0x1000004,0x404,0x10404,0x1010400,0x404,0x1000400,0x1000400,0,0x10004,0x10400,0,0x1010004);
    var spfunction2 = new Array (-0x7fef7fe0,-0x7fff8000,0x8000,0x108020,0x100000,0x20,-0x7fefffe0,-0x7fff7fe0,-0x7fffffe0,-0x7fef7fe0,-0x7fef8000,-0x80000000,-0x7fff8000,0x100000,0x20,-0x7fefffe0,0x108000,0x100020,-0x7fff7fe0,0,-0x80000000,0x8000,0x108020,-0x7ff00000,0x100020,-0x7fffffe0,0,0x108000,0x8020,-0x7fef8000,-0x7ff00000,0x8020,0,0x108020,-0x7fefffe0,0x100000,-0x7fff7fe0,-0x7ff00000,-0x7fef8000,0x8000,-0x7ff00000,-0x7fff8000,0x20,-0x7fef7fe0,0x108020,0x20,0x8000,-0x80000000,0x8020,-0x7fef8000,0x100000,-0x7fffffe0,0x100020,-0x7fff7fe0,-0x7fffffe0,0x100020,0x108000,0,-0x7fff8000,0x8020,-0x80000000,-0x7fefffe0,-0x7fef7fe0,0x108000);
    var spfunction3 = new Array (0x208,0x8020200,0,0x8020008,0x8000200,0,0x20208,0x8000200,0x20008,0x8000008,0x8000008,0x20000,0x8020208,0x20008,0x8020000,0x208,0x8000000,0x8,0x8020200,0x200,0x20200,0x8020000,0x8020008,0x20208,0x8000208,0x20200,0x20000,0x8000208,0x8,0x8020208,0x200,0x8000000,0x8020200,0x8000000,0x20008,0x208,0x20000,0x8020200,0x8000200,0,0x200,0x20008,0x8020208,0x8000200,0x8000008,0x200,0,0x8020008,0x8000208,0x20000,0x8000000,0x8020208,0x8,0x20208,0x20200,0x8000008,0x8020000,0x8000208,0x208,0x8020000,0x20208,0x8,0x8020008,0x20200);
    var spfunction4 = new Array (0x802001,0x2081,0x2081,0x80,0x802080,0x800081,0x800001,0x2001,0,0x802000,0x802000,0x802081,0x81,0,0x800080,0x800001,0x1,0x2000,0x800000,0x802001,0x80,0x800000,0x2001,0x2080,0x800081,0x1,0x2080,0x800080,0x2000,0x802080,0x802081,0x81,0x800080,0x800001,0x802000,0x802081,0x81,0,0,0x802000,0x2080,0x800080,0x800081,0x1,0x802001,0x2081,0x2081,0x80,0x802081,0x81,0x1,0x2000,0x800001,0x2001,0x802080,0x800081,0x2001,0x2080,0x800000,0x802001,0x80,0x800000,0x2000,0x802080);
    var spfunction5 = new Array (0x100,0x2080100,0x2080000,0x42000100,0x80000,0x100,0x40000000,0x2080000,0x40080100,0x80000,0x2000100,0x40080100,0x42000100,0x42080000,0x80100,0x40000000,0x2000000,0x40080000,0x40080000,0,0x40000100,0x42080100,0x42080100,0x2000100,0x42080000,0x40000100,0,0x42000000,0x2080100,0x2000000,0x42000000,0x80100,0x80000,0x42000100,0x100,0x2000000,0x40000000,0x2080000,0x42000100,0x40080100,0x2000100,0x40000000,0x42080000,0x2080100,0x40080100,0x100,0x2000000,0x42080000,0x42080100,0x80100,0x42000000,0x42080100,0x2080000,0,0x40080000,0x42000000,0x80100,0x2000100,0x40000100,0x80000,0,0x40080000,0x2080100,0x40000100);
    var spfunction6 = new Array (0x20000010,0x20400000,0x4000,0x20404010,0x20400000,0x10,0x20404010,0x400000,0x20004000,0x404010,0x400000,0x20000010,0x400010,0x20004000,0x20000000,0x4010,0,0x400010,0x20004010,0x4000,0x404000,0x20004010,0x10,0x20400010,0x20400010,0,0x404010,0x20404000,0x4010,0x404000,0x20404000,0x20000000,0x20004000,0x10,0x20400010,0x404000,0x20404010,0x400000,0x4010,0x20000010,0x400000,0x20004000,0x20000000,0x4010,0x20000010,0x20404010,0x404000,0x20400000,0x404010,0x20404000,0,0x20400010,0x10,0x4000,0x20400000,0x404010,0x4000,0x400010,0x20004010,0,0x20404000,0x20000000,0x400010,0x20004010);
    var spfunction7 = new Array (0x200000,0x4200002,0x4000802,0,0x800,0x4000802,0x200802,0x4200800,0x4200802,0x200000,0,0x4000002,0x2,0x4000000,0x4200002,0x802,0x4000800,0x200802,0x200002,0x4000800,0x4000002,0x4200000,0x4200800,0x200002,0x4200000,0x800,0x802,0x4200802,0x200800,0x2,0x4000000,0x200800,0x4000000,0x200800,0x200000,0x4000802,0x4000802,0x4200002,0x4200002,0x2,0x200002,0x4000000,0x4000800,0x200000,0x4200800,0x802,0x200802,0x4200800,0x802,0x4000002,0x4200802,0x4200000,0x200800,0,0x2,0x4200802,0,0x200802,0x4200000,0x800,0x4000002,0x4000800,0x800,0x200002);
    var spfunction8 = new Array (0x10001040,0x1000,0x40000,0x10041040,0x10000000,0x10001040,0x40,0x10000000,0x40040,0x10040000,0x10041040,0x41000,0x10041000,0x41040,0x1000,0x40,0x10040000,0x10000040,0x10001000,0x1040,0x41000,0x40040,0x10040040,0x10041000,0x1040,0,0,0x10040040,0x10000040,0x10001000,0x41040,0x40000,0x41040,0x40000,0x10041000,0x1000,0x40,0x10040040,0x1000,0x41040,0x10001000,0x40,0x10000040,0x10040000,0x10040040,0x10000000,0x40000,0x10001040,0,0x10041040,0x40040,0x10000040,0x10040000,0x10001000,0x10001040,0,0x10041040,0x41000,0x41000,0x1040,0x1040,0x40040,0x10000000,0x10041000);

    //create the 16 or 48 subkeys we will need
    var keys = des_createKeys (key);
    var m=0, i, j, temp, temp2, right1, right2, left, right, looping;
    var cbcleft, cbcleft2, cbcright, cbcright2
    var endloop, loopinc;
    var len = message.length;
    var chunk = 0;
    //set up the loops for single and triple des
    var iterations = keys.length == 32 ? 3 : 9; //single or triple des
    if (iterations == 3) {looping = encrypt ? new Array (0, 32, 2) : new Array (30, -2, -2);}
    else {looping = encrypt ? new Array (0, 32, 2, 62, 30, -2, 64, 96, 2) : new Array (94, 62, -2, 32, 64, 2, 30, -2, -2);}

    //pad the message depending on the padding parameter
    if (padding == 2) message += "        "; //pad the message with spaces
    else if (padding == 1) {temp = 8-(len%8); message += String.fromCharCode (temp,temp,temp,temp,temp,temp,temp,temp); if (temp==8) len+=8;} //PKCS7 padding
    else if (!padding) message += "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"; //pad the message out with null bytes

    //store the result here
    result = "";
    tempresult = "";

    if (mode == 1) { //CBC mode
        cbcleft = (iv.charCodeAt(m++) << 24) | (iv.charCodeAt(m++) << 16) | (iv.charCodeAt(m++) << 8) | iv.charCodeAt(m++);
        cbcright = (iv.charCodeAt(m++) << 24) | (iv.charCodeAt(m++) << 16) | (iv.charCodeAt(m++) << 8) | iv.charCodeAt(m++);
        m=0;
    }

    //loop through each 64 bit chunk of the message
    while (m < len) {
        left = (message.charCodeAt(m++) << 24) | (message.charCodeAt(m++) << 16) | (message.charCodeAt(m++) << 8) | message.charCodeAt(m++);
        right = (message.charCodeAt(m++) << 24) | (message.charCodeAt(m++) << 16) | (message.charCodeAt(m++) << 8) | message.charCodeAt(m++);

        //for Cipher Block Chaining mode, xor the message with the previous result
        if (mode == 1) {if (encrypt) {left ^= cbcleft; right ^= cbcright;} else {cbcleft2 = cbcleft; cbcright2 = cbcright; cbcleft = left; cbcright = right;}}

        //first each 64 but chunk of the message must be permuted according to IP
        temp = ((left >>> 4) ^ right) & 0x0f0f0f0f; right ^= temp; left ^= (temp << 4);
        temp = ((left >>> 16) ^ right) & 0x0000ffff; right ^= temp; left ^= (temp << 16);
        temp = ((right >>> 2) ^ left) & 0x33333333; left ^= temp; right ^= (temp << 2);
        temp = ((right >>> 8) ^ left) & 0x00ff00ff; left ^= temp; right ^= (temp << 8);
        temp = ((left >>> 1) ^ right) & 0x55555555; right ^= temp; left ^= (temp << 1);

        left = ((left << 1) | (left >>> 31));
        right = ((right << 1) | (right >>> 31));

        //do this either 1 or 3 times for each chunk of the message
        for (j=0; j<iterations; j+=3) {
            endloop = looping[j+1];
            loopinc = looping[j+2];
            //now go through and perform the encryption or decryption
            for (i=looping[j]; i!=endloop; i+=loopinc) { //for efficiency
                right1 = right ^ keys[i];
                right2 = ((right >>> 4) | (right << 28)) ^ keys[i+1];
                //the result is attained by passing these bytes through the S selection functions
                temp = left;
                left = right;
                right = temp ^ (spfunction2[(right1 >>> 24) & 0x3f] | spfunction4[(right1 >>> 16) & 0x3f]
                    | spfunction6[(right1 >>>  8) & 0x3f] | spfunction8[right1 & 0x3f]
                    | spfunction1[(right2 >>> 24) & 0x3f] | spfunction3[(right2 >>> 16) & 0x3f]
                    | spfunction5[(right2 >>>  8) & 0x3f] | spfunction7[right2 & 0x3f]);
            }
            temp = left; left = right; right = temp; //unreverse left and right
        } //for either 1 or 3 iterations

        //move then each one bit to the right
        left = ((left >>> 1) | (left << 31));
        right = ((right >>> 1) | (right << 31));

        //now perform IP-1, which is IP in the opposite direction
        temp = ((left >>> 1) ^ right) & 0x55555555; right ^= temp; left ^= (temp << 1);
        temp = ((right >>> 8) ^ left) & 0x00ff00ff; left ^= temp; right ^= (temp << 8);
        temp = ((right >>> 2) ^ left) & 0x33333333; left ^= temp; right ^= (temp << 2);
        temp = ((left >>> 16) ^ right) & 0x0000ffff; right ^= temp; left ^= (temp << 16);
        temp = ((left >>> 4) ^ right) & 0x0f0f0f0f; right ^= temp; left ^= (temp << 4);

        //for Cipher Block Chaining mode, xor the message with the previous result
        if (mode == 1) {if (encrypt) {cbcleft = left; cbcright = right;} else {left ^= cbcleft2; right ^= cbcright2;}}
        tempresult += String.fromCharCode ((left>>>24), ((left>>>16) & 0xff), ((left>>>8) & 0xff), (left & 0xff), (right>>>24), ((right>>>16) & 0xff), ((right>>>8) & 0xff), (right & 0xff));

        chunk += 8;
        if (chunk == 512) {result += tempresult; tempresult = ""; chunk = 0;}
    } //for every 8 characters, or 64 bits in the message

    //return the result as an array
    return result + tempresult;
} //end of des
```

In case it may be relevant, I have changed the way the request is made too. When the user clicks login, the following promise is called:

```
Ntlm.login('url')
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Success');
                appSettings.setString('token', 'abc123');
                this.router.navigate(['/ilt']);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Failed');
                appSettings.remove('token');
                alert('Failed! ' + error );
            })
```

I created a new login function in the ntlm.js file:

```
Ntlm.login = function(url) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!Ntlm.domain || !Ntlm.username || !Ntlm.lmHashedPassword || !Ntlm.ntHashedPassword) {

            Ntlm.error('No NTLM credentials specified. Use Ntlm.setCredentials(...) before making calls.');
        }
        var hostname = Ntlm.getLocation(url).hostname;
        var msg1 = Ntlm.createMessage1(hostname);
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onload = function() {
            var response = request.getResponseHeader('WWW-Authenticate');
            var challenge = Ntlm.getChallenge(response);

            var msg3 = Ntlm.createMessage3(challenge, hostname);
            request.open('GET', url, false);
            var authorization = 'NTLM ' + msg3.toBase64();
            request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorization);

            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    resolve(request.status);
                }
                else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status != 200) {
                    reject(request.status);
                }
            };
            request.send(null);
        };
        request.open('GET', url, false);
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'NTLM ' + msg1.toBase64());
        request.send(null);   
    })

};
```

This is all working fine on the Android version, just cant understand why it isnt on ios. Very frustrating! If anyone can make sense of this, I would be eternally grateful. I realise it is a lot of code and quite niche area!

Many thanks,

---

UPDATE

I think there may be a difference in the way console.log behaves in Android and iOS, which could explain some of the missing characters. I created a new test account (testuser / testing), and logged various points to try and establish what was happening in the NTLM process step by step. Here are the logs for android:

```
NTLM WALKTHROUGH ON ANDROID

Step 1: Creates a cryptographic hash of the users password:
lmHashedPassword = -UE}{}*ªÓ´5µî
ntHashedPassword = |SÏ¥ê}�;�� ûQ£õ

Step 2: Sends first request to the server, with the following Authorisation header:
NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAA7IAAAUABQBEAAAAJAAkACAAAABHQVRFV0FZLlNUUEFVTFNDQVRIT0xJQ0NPTExFR0UuQ08uVUtBRE1JTg==

Step 3: Server sends a challenge back to client:
¡2@�³Q%Ï

Step 4: Client encrypts this challenge with the hash of the users password and sends back to server (response).
The Authorization header is: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAKQAAAAYABgAvAAAAAoACgBAAAAAEgASAEoAAABIAEgAXAAAAAAAAADUAAAAAYIAAEEARABNAEkATgB0AGUAcwB0AHMAdABhAGYAZgBHAEEAVABFAFcAQQBZAC4AUwBUAFAAQQBVAEwAUwBDAEEAVABIAE8ATABJAEMAQwBPAEwATABFAEcARQAuAEMATwAuAFUASwBsEslcvTQhhY3+RgKtqufBzFrmufFKNkAHXJRcA6ThOAU105+NJBGnsn2ri6Ziuv8=

Step 5: Now the server has sent the username, challenge and response to the Domain Controller.
The DC compares and returns status of: 200
```

Here are the logs for iOS:

```
NTLM WALKTHROUGH ON IOS

Step 1: Creates a cryptographic hash of the users password:
lmHashedPassword = -UE}{}*ªÓ´5µî
ntHashedPassword = |SÏ¥ê}�;�� ûQ£õ

Step 2: Sends the first request to the server, with the following Authorisation header:
NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAA7IAAAUABQBEAAAAJAAkACAAAABHQVRFV0FZLlNUUEFVTFNDQVRIT0xJQ0NPTExFR0UuQ08uVUtBRE1JTg==

Step 3: Server sends a challenge back to client:
q�v¹,

Step 4: Client encrypts this challenge with the hash of the users password and sends back to server (response).
The Authorization header is: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAKQAAAAYABgAvAAAAAoACgBAAAAAEgASAEoAAABIAEgAXAAAAAAAAADUAAAAAYIAAEEARABNAEkATgB0AGUAcwB0AHMAdABhAGYAZgBHAEEAVABFAFcAQQBZAC4AUwBUAFAAQQBVAEwAUwBDAEEAVABIAE8ATABJAEMAQwBPAEwATABFAEcARQAuAEMATwAuAFUASwAP9HN5WjPCs9hMRrmttnYHieFrThwyUAWanKWtVdzOqDOJ2isUdQeV0ISmv9TT0ek=

Step 5: Now the server has sent the username, challenge and response to the Domain Controller.
The DC compares returns status of: 401
```

Seems the credentials are worked out the same, and then the challenge returned from the server is random. But on iOS, the challenge seems to be missing characters - possibly due to the type of characters. The client then encrypts the challenge with the hashed passwords and sends back to the server. I imagine it might be this part which is not correct on iOS.

Comment: As you say, the difference seems to be in `des`. It is somewhat long, so a little more debugging would help to pinpoint the divergence between Android and iOS. Just as an example, check if the times the loop `while (m < len)` is traversed is the same (given the return value for iOS and the line `return result + tempresult;`). What is the return value in Android?

Comment: I did check and the while loop was looping same number of times. The return values were different each time between iOS and android when `des()` was called inside the `Ntlm.buildResponse()` function. I guess because each time the NTLM is run, there is a random challenge used to encrypt responses. So it would be impossible to see if the iOS and Android versions matched for those stages.